# formatRelativeTime in TTTableMessageItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, three20

I'm new to Three20, so this may seem like a very simple question.

How can I get the timestamp in TTTableMessageItem to be in relative 
time format?

If it is not doable using TTTableMessageItem, what would you recommend 
me to do to achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The function formatRelativeTime in NSDateAdditions is what you are looking for. Since this is a category function you can call it in on any NSDate object as long as you include NSDateAdditions.h in Three20Core

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As TTTableMessageItem is expecting NSDate for timestamp:, I can't pass formatRelativeTime string object to timestamp:.

Am I missing something? How should I do it? Thanks.